# IF ... Elif...Else flow

Tags: python, control-flow

I created a function with an if flow control, I am wondering a few things about it.

```
class Supplier(Process):

    def weeklySupply(self):
        global D1Vals
        xMeet = D1Vals[0]
        lead = 0
        capac = 150.0
        supply = 0
        if stocked.amount >= 15000:
            supply = 0
            yield put, self, stocked, supply
            S1Vals.append(0)
        elif supply >= capac:
            supply = capac
            yield put, self, stocked, supply
            S1Vals.append(capac)
        else:
            supply = random.triangular(.70 * xMeet , xMeet , xMeet * 1.05)
            yield put, self, stocked, supply
            print ('Week:'+'%6.0f:Supplied: %6.0f units. CurSupply = %6.0f' %
                   (now() + 1., supply, stocked.amount))
            yield hold, self, lead
            S1Vals.append(supply)
            del D1Vals[0]
```

What I though I coded was:

- If the amount in the stocked object was >= 15000, then the object generates zero supply
  or if a supply value was generated which was greater than a predefined 'capac' amount, then the supply value = 'capac'.
- If non of the above were true then the supply value was generated as a random distribution. When I get my output though, the supply value does exceed the 'capac' value of 150.

Have I misunderstood how to do the flow?

Comment: Where is `stocked.amount` defined?

Comment: I guess your `random.triangular(.70 * xMeet , xMeet , xMeet * 1.05)` calculation can still go higher than `capac`..

Comment: Also, you normally yield 4 values (`put, self, stocked, supply`), but in your else branch you *also* yield 3 values (`hold, self, lead`). Make sure that whatever consumes this generator takes this into account and not 'make up' a value for the 4th parameter, which happens to be `supply`.

Comment: The `elif supply >= capac` condition will never be entered since `supply` and `capac` have fixed values at that point.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , if stocked.amount is less than 15000 and supply is less than capac, then it should still add to stocked.amount. I am thinking of 'capac' as a producers maximum capacity for example, and the 'stocked' is a 'store'.

Comment: A self-contained script that fully shows your results might help (eg, we can also see where stocked.amount comes from, or what D1vals contains; the latter after all defines the maximum value you can get from random.triangular).

Comment: @MartijnPieters. I see what you are saying, I never thought about limiting the random distribution value, beginner here!! Is there a more efficient way I could be doing this? In the meantime I will try and work on it myself.

Comment: @interjay. true, I had to declare supply = 0 , because I get an error otherwise, as my actual supply distribution value does not appear untill the else statement. It is probably my own inexperience on this.

Comment: @manengstudent: use a `min(supply, capac)` operation? That'll cap supply to the capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mixup the `if elif` construct with some kind of `or` as you did in your question. The   `elif` condition will only be evaluated if the `if` condition is `False`. 
I think, what you really want is:

```
if stocked.amount >= 15000:
    if supply >= capac:
        supply = capac
        yield put, self, stocked, supply
        S1Vals.append(capac)
     else:
        supply = 0
        yield put, self, stocked, supply
        S1Vals.append(0)
else:
    supply = random.triangular(.70 * xMeet , xMeet , xMeet * 1.05)
    ...
```

But this would only work, if `supply` is not initialised with 0 at the beginning of the function.

Comment: My `S1Vals.append(0)` stops functioning in this structure, it seems to not append to the list

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work a treat, and some nice things for me to think about. Only issue I can see is now my S1Vals list has stopped having the zero supply appended to the list. I can see this on my output graph and also when i do a len(S1Vals). The final code is with your suggestions is:

```
if stocked.amount >= 15000:
        if supply >= capac:
            supply = capac
            S1Vals.append(capac)
            yield put, self, stocked, supply
        else: 
            supply = 0.0
            yield put, self, stocked, supply
            S1Vals.append(supply)
    else:
        supply = min(capac, random.triangular(.70 * xMeet , xMeet , xMeet * 1.05))
        yield put, self, stocked, supply
        print ('Week:'+'%6.0f:Supplied: %6.0f units. CurSupply = %6.0f' %
               (now() + 1., supply, stocked.amount))
        yield hold, self, lead
        S1Vals.append(supply)
        del D1Vals[0]
```

To get here I used the flow suggestion above from MaxPower, also  `min(supply,capac)`, and declared a `global supply`. The last issue seems that `supply = 0.0` never kicks in, but it should really?

Comment: You have to think about the relation of your conditions. Which condition one is the stronger one in your model?

Comment: @MaxPowers .I understand it as  the main `if..else` saying that `stocked.amount >= 15000` then the inside `if...else` needs to be decided or else the 'outside' `else:` kicks in. When I read it my requirement is:
`supply = 0` when `stocked.amount` exceed 15000
`supply`` can never be greater than `capac`
any other scenario fits the outside `else:` statement.